# How to convert string to datetime using InnerElement

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I managed to store value from string to datetime format but it's not working,Can you guys help

```
public List<CaseListEntry> GetCaseListEntries()
    {
        var CaseGridTrs = CaseListGrid.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr"));
        var entryList = CaseGridTrs.Select(x => 
        {
            var CaseEntryTds = x.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td"));
            return new CaseListEntry
            {

                Register = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(0).FindElement(By.XPath(".//a")).Text,
                DateTime = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(1).Text.----------?
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you just trying to convert a string into a DateTime?

Comment: Yes just string into DateTime

Comment: In which case there are many, many questions about this. Try looking at those.